# Opera clears cookie on close

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cookies, opera

Opera seems to be clearing cookies when a user closes the browser - despite the fact that it's based on Chromium and is pretty much the same as Chrome. On every other browsers - even IE, the cookies get saved - except Opera.

Is it a feature or a bug? Does anyone how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be up to the user and not the developer? At least there is a setting in Opera to delete cookies on close.

Comment: Is there? I couldn't find it. Could you please tell me where it is?

Comment: At least according to this: http://www.opera.com/help/tutorials/security/privacy/

Comment: Weird, I only see these options:
*Allow local data to be set (recommended) < this is what I've enabled
*Keep local data only until I quit my browser
*Block sites from setting any data
*Block third-party cookies and site data

Comment: Can't confirm this, my cookies survive closing Opera just fine. If you click on "All cookies and site data..." below the settings you mention, you should see all stored cookies, e.g. for stackoverflow. Are you sure you haven't got any weird exceptions, or that this isn't due to strange write permissions to wherever you're storing your cookies...?